# How come sending a request context gives me access to a setting in my Django template?

Tags: django

In my view, if I specify

```
def myView(request):
    return render_to_response('myTemplate.html', {'user': request.user,}, 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

then I can access settings such as `STATIC_URL` in myTemplate.html.

However, if I specify

```
def myView(request):
        return render_to_response('myTemplate.html', {'user': request.user,})
```

then I cannot access `STATIC_URL`. In this latter case, `{{ STATIC_URL }}` just yields an empty string in the rendered page. In the former case, `{{ STATIC_URL }}` yields the proper string for the static URL ("/static/").

Why do I need to send a request context to access the `STATIC_URL` setting in my template?

I am running Django 1.4 on Apache 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) for a better answer. But there is the short answer:

This is because of DRY (Don´t Repeat Yourself), think this: what if you need set the same variable in all the templates through all the views?: context_processors, are methods that add variables to your templates in a more ordered way.

I quote:

> Django comes with a special Context class, django.template.RequestContext, that acts slightly differently than the normal django.template.Context. The first difference is that it takes an HttpRequest as its first argument. For example:

```
c = RequestContext(request, {
    'foo': 'bar',
})
```

> The second difference is that it automatically populates the context with a few variables, according to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting.

Answer (score 1):

To access the `STATIC_URL` setting you need to send a request context because by default the `RequestContext` instance is automatically populated with some variable, accordingly with the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` settings which, by default too, reads this:

```
(...
"django.core.context_processors.static",
...)
```

About the `django.core.context_processors.static` context processor, the docs states:

> If TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS contains this processor, every
>   RequestContext will contain a variable STATIC_URL, providing the value
>   of the STATIC_URL setting.

If instead, you don't specify the `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` part. Consider this signature:

```
render_to_response(template_name[, dictionary][, context_instance][, mimetype])
```

In this case a basic `Context` instance is used and (for this reason) only the given `dictionary` items get injected into the template. This dictionary could or couldn't contain the value of `settings.STATIC_URL`.

Note: as pointed out in another answer, since Django 1.3 you can directly use the `render` shortcut instead of `render_to_response()` with a `context_instance` argument.

References to official documentation:

- [render_to_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response)
- [Subclassing Context: RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)
- [django.core.context_processors.static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS)
- [render shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on 1.4, use the newer [render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut. Then you can do:

```
def myView(request):
        return render(request, 'myTemplate.html', {'user': request.user,})
```

Comment: Yeah, fair enough, but I think it addresses the underlying issue, which is "Why do I have to pass this redundant nonsense?"